# Is posting informative content without a real question acceptable?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

I’ve made an interesting (to me) discovery about something I’ve been working on, but I don’t know if I should post it on any of the math-related stack exchange forums since there isn’t much of a question involved. Specifically, I want to share that Classical Propositional Logic is contained in another, strictly more expressive propositional logic and a basic sketch of a proof. Is such a post allowed on math.stackexchange.com or math.overflow.com?

Comment: It is probably not exactly the same, but you might have a look at this post: [Recently rolled out SE Encyclopedia feature.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4286) And you can also check various other discussions [linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4286). (At the same time, I think this depends on the question. Probably somebody more familiar with logic question on this site would be able to say whether your specific topis is of interest.)

Answer (score 8):

No.  That is not suitable for this site.  We are a question-and-answer site.  If you want to advertise a new result, then you'll need to use some other way to get the word out -- for example, a personal blog.

If there is a concrete question, then you can post a question and answer it yourself.  But the question still needs to meet all the usual quality standards.